# Use Dynamic Programming (memoization) to get this function below 2^n time complexity

Tags: java, dynamic-programming, memoization, np-hard

I have a recursive algorithm that I wrote, which splits an array and finds the minimum of the differences between the two resulting arrays. For example:

If the input array was: [1,2,2,3,3] the minimum difference would be 1. ((1+2+2) - (3+3)).
If the input array was: [1,100,4,2] the minimum difference would be 93. (100 - (1+4+2)).

My algorithm is O(2^n) time complexity. I'm trying to use DP with memoization to lower the runtime.

The best that I've achieved is O(2^n / 2) using this memo that prunes half of the recursions, in the worst case. Worst case is that all sums for each level are unique.

How can I do better?

```
public static int minDiffRecursive(int[] nums) {
    int sum = 0;
    
    for(int num : nums) {
        sum += num;
    }
    
    int[][] memo = new int[nums.length][sum];

    for(int[] row : memo) {
        Arrays.fill(row, -1);
    }
    return move(nums, 0, 0, 0, memo);
}

private static int move(int[] nums, int i, int sum1, int sum2, int[][] memo) {
    if(i >= nums.length) return Math.abs(sum1 - sum2); //if at the end, return difference
    if(memo[i][Math.min(sum1, sum2)] > -1) return memo[i][Math.min(sum1, sum2)]; //take the min of sum1 and sum2, which are mirror images for each i. Return stored value if exists.

    int add1 = move(nums, i + 1, sum1 + nums[i], sum2, memo); //check path adding item to sum1
    int add2 = move(nums, i + 1, sum1, sum2 + nums[i], memo); //check path adding item to sum2

    return memo[i][Math.min(sum1, sum2)] = Math.min(add1, add2); //return the minimum of the two paths
}
```

Comment: Do you split the array at an index and have to arrays, one to the left and one to the right of the index? Or can you pick numbers randomly into two arrays?

Comment: I don't ever actually split the array. 

I have two sums, sum1 and sum2 that track the totals for what each array would be. At each recursion I add to one of these two totals.

If it helps you visualize it, you could see it as adding one of the items to one of the two arrays at each step, but it is actually adding to one of the two sums.

Comment: Why ist the minimum difference of `[1,100,4,2]` not `1-(100+4+2) = -105`? It's clearly smaller than `93`.

Comment: Also, are you sure your algorithm is `O(2^n / 2)`? I added a counter right after `if(memo[i]..` to see how often the function is called. By calling `minDiffRecursive` with an array of 30 elements, the counter was incremented to some value below 1000. That's nowhere near `2^30`...

Comment: @AlexR it is the WORST case time complexity. If you have an array where the memo will never be used. Ex: [1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256,512], it is O(2^n / 2). 

There are many cases where it is better, but it is indeed that slow in the worst case.

Comment: @AlexR it's the smallest difference in absolute value. No negative numbers.

Comment: I'm not able to think any more today, but it seems related to what is discussed [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/split-first-n-natural-numbers-into-two-sets-with-minimum-absolute-difference-of-their-sums/), they arrive at O(N) due to the circumstance that iteratively forming 2 sums with minimal intermediary difference (while putting their components in 2 resulting sets) will yield 2 final sums with minimum difference and the two sets of their constituents. or so it seems. Maybe sorting is necessary up front (O(n log n))